# How can I receive only the computer names which are accessible for me at this time?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Windows 7 domain network.

I get the domain computer names:

```
List<String> compNames = new List<String>();

// If it isn't possible to be connected to a domain 
// network then we will receive an exception.
using (DirectoryEntry domainEntry = domain.GetDirectoryEntry())
using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(
    domainEntry, "objectClass=computer", new[] { "Name" }))
using (SearchResultCollection resultCollection =
    searcher.FindAll()) {
    foreach (SearchResult searchResult in resultCollection) {
        compNames.Add(searchResult.Properties["Name"][0]
            .ToString());
    }
}
```

This code returns also the names of computers which already are not existing many years and the computers which are off. How can I recive only the computer names which are accessible for me at this time? Is it possible?

Comment: You need to ping computers to check whether they are on or off

Comment: This is very slow method when I process many computer names.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to `ping` each computer on domain to check their accessibility.

Below function you can use to ping computer:

```
        public String PingTest(string asMac)
        {
            String lsReturn = "";
            try
            {
                Ping pingreq = new Ping();
                PingReply rep = pingreq.Send(asMac);
                if (rep.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    lsReturn = "Success"
                    return lsReturn;
                }
                else
                {
                    lsReturn = "Error Pinging " + asMac + " " + rep.Status;
                }

            }
            catch (PingException pEx)
            {
                lsReturn = "PingException Error Pinging " + asMac + " " + pEx.Message + Environment.NewLine + pEx.StackTrace;
            }
            catch (NetworkInformationException nEx)
            {
                lsReturn = "NetworkInformationException Error Pinging " + asMac + " " + nEx.Message + Environment.NewLine + nEx.StackTrace;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lsReturn = "Error Pinging " + asMac + " " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace;
            }
            return lsReturn;
       }
```